# User Management / Get iduser

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, userid

I'm creating a user management where you can change a user's role, USER or ADMIN.

I'm a beginner in Laravel 9, and I would like to know how can I get the iduser when I click on the user's button ? For example this is a user profile.
The button can change his role form user to admin but I can't get his id...

I tried this but it's written 0 instead of 2 (his iduser)

```
        $userID = User::find('iduser');
        dd($userID);
```

Thank you very much!

Edit : When I click on a user profile, I want to get HIS/HER id, not mine or logged user :)

FOR EXAMPLE :

This user, I click on "Changer en administrateur" (change to admin), I just want his id ;)

[image]

Comment: It should be in the data array you pass from the controller to view. Post the data set and controller code

Comment: @brombeer Its's not about the logged-in user.

Comment: You have to pass it from frontend to the controller. And in controller you can access it with `$request`. Like `$request->iduser` or whatever is your key for that

Comment: The [`find`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_find) method returns an Eloquent Model based on the given key so you need to know that before using `find`. The [`where`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_where) method allows you to search based on other fields. Do you want the `ID` of the authenticated `User` or a different `User`? Please update your question to add more detail and clarity.

Comment: When I click on a user profile I want to get his/her id, not mine or logged user ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$request->validate([
            'type' => 'required',
        ]);
    
        DB::table('users')
            ->where('iduser', $request->iduser)
            ->update(
                ['type' => $request->type]
            );
```

This one works to select a user's id :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get logged in user id you can do

```
$userID = Auth::user()->id;
```

Either from User model ,try

```
$userID = User::all()->pluck('id');
```

Comment: You can just use Auth::userId()