# LARAVEL 9 - Get User ID for user management

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I'm creating a users management with Laravel 9, I am an administrator and I would like to change users to admins whenever I like :)

For example this user ->

[image]

I wrote this code ->

```
        public function UpdateToAdminAction(Request $request) {

        $request->validate([
            'type' => 'required|exists:users',
        ]);

        DB::table('users')->update(
            ['type' => $request->type]
        );

        return redirect('/gestion-administrateurs');
    }
```

But I cannot update THIS user's type, this code changes ALL users' types lol, it's not what I wanted. Do you know with this code, how can I change THIS user's type ?

Thanks, I hope you'll understand my request ^^

Comment: Bro, you need to add the where condition.

Comment: you are updating all the users, to update only one query for a specific id like `DB::table('users')->where('id',1)->update(
            ['type' => $request->type]
        );`

Comment: You have previously asked this same question. [User Management / Get iduser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73568890/user-management-get-iduser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass user ID as route part, or as request param

For example, you may create following route for updating users:

```php
// Dont forget to protect this route with middleware like "can:edit-users"!
Route::post('/user/{id}', 'UserController@update');
```

then, render in template button to made user admin:

```html
<form method="post" action="/user/{{ $user->id }}">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="admin">
    <button type="submit">Make admin</button>
</form>
```

And create update method:

```php
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'type' => 'required|exists:users',
    ]);

    DB::table('users')
        ->where('id', $request->id)
        ->update(
            ['type' => $request->type]
        );

    return redirect('/somewhere');
}
```

Comment: WAH thanks a lot it works ! Update method i coded something like this before but I totally forgot to change the the route and the action !! THANKS !!!!

Comment: You are not receiving any param on update method, why did you added it on route?

Comment: `$request->id` will be `null` here

Comment: @Moshiur, Route params will be set as Request object properties by framework, you can test it [here](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/f5be0173-9aa9-484f-8818-bd8912011a73)

Answer (score 1):

you are selecting all the users by this query `DB::table('users')`,

***assuming you are receiving id in request***

you must select one row by adding a where condition `DB::table('users')->where('id',$request->id)->update(['type' => $request->type])`

Comment: public function UpdateToAdminAction(Request $request) {

            $request->validate([
                'iduser' => 'required',
                'type' => 'required|exists:users',
            ]);

            DB::table('users')->where('iduser', $request->iduser)->update(['type' => $request->type]);

            return redirect('/gestion-administrateurs');
        }

This is what I coded according to your answer (id is iduser on PHPMyAdmin ;)) but it doesn't work, I go on admins page but without my user updated :(

Comment: May be you are not passing iduser on request, try with an id first like -DB::table('users')->where('id',1)->update(['type' => $request->type])